# Generate Random Cell inputs from a list across multiple Columns without repeats across Rows

Tags: excel, vba, random, excel-formula, generator

I'm attempting to generate a random output off the same list of inputs across multiple columns, but without having the same input repeated more than an ~n number of times across the same row. There are a couple items I'm working on using this for, but for simplicity, I'm using the following example/data.

I have a column of names (Column C), 1-6, First name listed in Row 2. In Row 1, spanning columns D-O, are periods of time. To keep it simple, I've labeled them "Week 1" ; "Week 2" ; etc.

In column A, I have a list of 6 generic 'assignments' to match with the 6 names. My formula is in D3:O3, and is the following:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY($A$3:$A$8,RANDARRAY(COUNTA($A$3:$A$8))),SEQUENCE(6))
```

This gives me a random output of the list in column A for each respective Week, but I cannot figure out how to set the number of times an item from the list in col A can appear across col D-O (Week 1-12). See example below, where I have 6 'assignments' in the list, however, the repetition of each could be 0-6. I'd like to have an input to determine the number of times an item in the list can repeat across the row, for example -- with 6 items in the list, I'd like to limit each to only appear twice for a given row/name. If there's 12+, they can only appear once, if there's 3, they can appear 3 times, etc.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is possible using a formula, or if VBA would be required/more practical, but I haven't attempted to go down that road yet.

Attempted to incorporate the UNIQUE( function as well, but couldn't determine how to incorporate it properly, and multiple google searches turned up empty.

**EDIT #1 --** I realized I forgot to include the 2nd parameter, where I'm looking to having an additional restriction on the # of repeats that occur down the columns, in addition to the # of repeats across the rows. With this example, the ideal output would look something like this, but randomized vs. this 'step-down' look.
[image]

Comment: sidenote: your repeat count table has an error, seems wrongly count first week.

Comment: I don't understand `if there's 3, they can appear 3 times` --> shouldn't this be `4 times` (3*4 = 12). As a consequence this would mean that each item occurs equally often. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: @Ike looks like I mis-typed, you'd be correct in it being 4. Ideally, I'd like to have an input box in say B3, that's "1, 2, 3, 4, etc." whatever I want the number of repeats to be across the column, regardless the # of items in the list of col A or how many columns I end up having extend to the right. Sorry, I typed this up late last night, otherwise does the question make sense?

Comment: @Blackcat the repeat count table is more just a check. I'd turned calculations off while working on this and was doing it manually, if there's an error there, it's probably just because I didn't perform an updated Calc. For this example, I'd like to see "2" in each box of that repeat count check table.

Answer (score 1):

if you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(l,list[List],
maxRepeat,C2,
cntWeeks,COLUMNS(F1:Q1),
names,E2:E5,
λRandom, LAMBDA(l,maxRepeat,cntWeeks,
                LET(repeatedList, INDEX(l,SEQUENCE(ROWS(l)*maxRepeat,,1,1/maxRepeat)),
                    randomSort,SORTBY(repeatedList,RANDARRAY(ROWS(l)*maxRepeat)),
                    TOROW(TAKE(randomSort,cntWeeks)))),
DROP(REDUCE("",names,LAMBDA(r,x,VSTACK(r,λRandom(l,maxRepeat,cntWeeks)))),1))
```

`λRandom` creates the extended list of values based on maxRepeat, then sorts this list randomly and takes the first 12 (= cntWeeks) values.

This is repeated for each name in E2:E5.

[image]

***UPDATE***

With this formula within a week every task appears exactly one time (6 tasks, 6 names):

```
=LET(weeks,D1:O1,tasks,list[List],
cntTasks,ROWS(tasks),cntWeeks,COLUMNS(weeks),
λRotateTasks,LAMBDA(start,SCAN(start-1, SEQUENCE(cntTasks),
                                                   LAMBDA(a,v,IF(a=cntTasks,1,a+1)))),
tasklist,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(cntWeeks),
                                     LAMBDA(result,i,HSTACK(result,SORTBY(list[List],λRotateTasks(MOD(i-1,cntTasks)+1))))),,1),
SORTBY(tasklist,RANDARRAY(1,cntWeeks)))
```

`λRotateTasks` creates - based on the start parameter - a list of numbers, e.g. 3,4,5,6,1,2 for start = 3. This is used to sort the tasklist.

These sorted tasklists are then randomly stacked together ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solved the question I asked. However, I'm not realizing I failed to include the full picture when creating the post, as that wasn't the issue I was having at the time.

Comment: The second parameter I was attempting to incorporate when creating the post wasn't included, as that wasn't the issue I was having at the time... So Essentially I'd like to have 2 max repeat inputs, one for the rows, or "weeks" and one for the columns, or "names." Does that make sense?

Comment: I've added an edit to the original post to hopefully clarify this some.

Comment: I was sure that you will come up with this requirement ... Can you explain why randomness is necessary? Why can't there be a kind of rotation logic? Could it be that there are less or more names than tasks? How would the solution then look like?

Comment: I added a further solution ...